# How can Conditional Formatting be applied if adjacent cells are populated?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to apply color to a cell if any of the adjacent range of cells are populated.

Example, I need to apply color to `H8` if any of the cells from `I8` to `AG8` are populated.

I have tried many things, this is the closest I came.

Rule formula:`=AND(NOT(ISBLANK($I8)))`

Applies to: `$H$8`

This works for one cell, although I need something like this: `=AND(NOT(ISBLANK($I8:$AG8)))`

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 determine if I8 to AG8 contain something

Formula [1] =IF(COUNTBLANK($I8:$AG8)=25,False,True)

if all cells are empty, there will be 25 from the countblank. Any other number shows something(s) are out there.

Step 2. Convert to a name flag
use the name manager to give the formula a name. Make sure the focus is on h8 or some other cell on the 8th row. The name manager is on the formula bar.

Step 3. Apply conditional by using a equation of =Flag

Comment: does not work any more help?

Comment: This is a training scheduling matrix file.  I am using columns (I through GC) grouped in 25 subject column groups detailing the different aspects of training available for each of the 25 subjects.  If I have a column group expanded and choose a few item columns by placing an (x) in the cells for a training class row and then collapse the column group I have no way of knowing there are any of the columns selected.  CONTINUED

Comment: What I am trying to do is if I expand a column group say Admin group column H.  The group now shows column H as the grouping and columns I through AG as the items within Admin group, and select a few cells for training I need the group column H to change color so I will know there are items selected within that group.

Comment: Please do not use the comments area to add details of the question. Use the **edit** link below your question to add details. Others who read your question above, may not see these details.

Comment: Were you able to make the named formula flag? if so, what happens if you put =flag in some of the cells to the right of all the data? Does it show true for rows where data is present and false where it is empty?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **COUNT** if cells `I8:AG8` contain numbers, or **COUNTA** if the cells contain text. These will count the number of cells containing data.

```
=COUNTA(I8:AG8)>0
```

If the result is greater than `0`, it will trigger the Conditional Format for `H8`.

Comment: Charlie  -  thanks  -  I used =COUNTIF(I8:AG8,"x") in the conditional format formula of cell H8 and now if any of the adjacent cells are filled the group cell applies a color

Comment: Good choice. There are a number of good ways to do it. You should post your own answer with an explanation of how you did it and how it answers your question.